# How to strip certain tags using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

How can I strip certain tags `<font style="vertical-align: inherit;">` `</font>` and keep the contents using JavaScript?

```
<div id="Box">
    <h1><font style="vertical-align: inherit;">
        <font style="vertical-align: inherit;">Meine Webseite</font></font>
    </h1>
    
    <p><font style="vertical-align: inherit;">
       <font style="vertical-align: inherit;">Hallo zusammen!</font></font>
    </p>
    
    <p><font style="vertical-align: inherit;">
       <font style="vertical-align: inherit;">Über diese Seite:</font></font>
    </p>
</div>
```

This should be the result:

```
<div id="Box">
        <h1>Meine Webseite</h1>
        
        <p>Hallo zusammen!</p>
        
        <p>Über diese Seite:</p>
</div>
```

Since I have several font tags I require a JavaScript solution for all.

Answer (score 1):

I wrote some human-readable code on codepen and it works fine.

```js
var font = document.querySelectorAll("#Box font");

for(let i=0; i<font.length; i++) {
  var parent = font[i].parentNode;
  console.log({parent})
  var text = document.createTextNode(font[i].innerText);
  parent.insertBefore(text, font[i])
  parent.removeChild(font[i])
}
```

Codepen Link => https://codepen.io/HARSH_VATS/pen/bGqeROz

Comment: thanks it works fine for a normal document, but how can I use it within here: https://www.w3schools.com/code/tryit.asp?filename=GQKBFE47DV8L  After running the code the left iframe has the font but it can no be removed in your way.

Comment: the google translator adds the <font> by translation. Now after the translation I want to remove the font in the html. Afterwards I would have the pure code without <font>. I tried to remove the font with your code. Usually it works with the console but for the google translator it does not. Do you know why?

Answer (score 1):

If you wanna handle it in plainJs use code below:

```
const boxNode = document.querySelector("#Box");
boxNode.querySelectorAll('font')
.forEach((el) => {
    const parent = el.parentElement;
    while (el.firstChild) parent.insertBefore(el.firstChild, el);
    parent.removeChild(el);
});
```

Comment: thanks it works fine for a normal document, but how can I use it within here: w3schools.com/code/tryit.asp?filename=GQKBFE47DV8L After running the code the left iframe has the font but it can no be removed in your way. Do you have a solution?

Comment: In a javascript way, you can remove/update/add/edit DOM but if you want to remove extra elements from your file I suggest you use task runners like Gulp, Grunt, and Webpack to handle this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Jquery Solution :

```
$('#Box').find('font').contents().unwrap()
```

Regex Solution :

```
let elm = document.getElementById("Box")
elm.innerHTML = elm.innerHTML.replaceAll(/<\/?font[^>]*>/g,"");
```

Comment: thanks but your code is jquery and not javascript

Comment: jQuery is javascript

Comment: @FredStark [no](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/335328/2427065)

Answer (score 0):

This works, although I'm not sure if it is very efficient

```js
const box = document.querySelector("#Box");

for (const textField of box.children) {
  for (const fontBlock of textField.children) {
    textField.innerText = fontBlock.innerText;
    fontBlock.remove();
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="Box">
  <h1>
    <font style="vertical-align: inherit;">
      <font style="vertical-align: inherit;">Meine Webseite</font>
    </font>
  </h1>

  <p>
    <font style="vertical-align: inherit;">
      <font style="vertical-align: inherit;">Hallo zusammen!</font>
    </font>
  </p>

  <p>
    <font style="vertical-align: inherit;">
      <font style="vertical-align: inherit;">Über diese Seite:</font>
    </font>
  </p>
</div>
```